# Two arrays of the same type, one getting updated and the other is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsobject

I have two arrays, one in a view controller (`var usersRooms: [Room] = []`), and the other in a `User` object (`var rooms: [Room] = []`). There's a reference to the object in the view controller (`var currentUser: User?`). A you can see, both arrays are of type `[Room]`.

In the function below I make a call to Firebase to retrieve the user's info and set the `User` object.

```
func getUserInfo() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
    let userRoomRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("rooms")
    self.currentUser?.uid = uid

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let usersDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            print("\n\nUserDict: \(usersDict)\n\n")
            guard let name = usersDict["name"] as? String else {print("Error getting user's name"); return}
            guard let handle = usersDict["handle"] else {print("Error getting user's handle"); return}
            guard let gender = usersDict["gender"] else {print("Error getting user's gender"); return}
            guard let profilePicture = usersDict["profilePicture"] else {print("Error getting user's profilePicture"); return}

            // how to get user's rooms from FB and add into User object's rooms array??
            userRoomRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (roomSnap) in

                for eachRoom in roomSnap.value as! [String : AnyObject] {
                    let roomID = eachRoom.key as! String
                    userRoomRef.child(roomID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (roomSnap) in

                        if let roomInfo = roomSnap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                            guard let roomName = roomInfo["roomName"] as! String! else {print("Error getting room name"); return}
                            guard let participants = roomInfo["participants"] as! [String]! else {print("Error getting room participants"); return}
                            print("\n\nRoom Name: \(roomName)\nRoom Participants: \(participants)\nRoom ID: \(roomID)\n")

                            self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))
                            self.currentUser?.rooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))

                            print("\n\nUser's Rooms: \(self.usersRooms)\n\n")
                            print("\n\nRooms (from currentUser): \(self.currentUser?.rooms)\n\n")
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            print("\nRoomsTableViewController User Values:\n\nName: \(name)\nHandle: \(handle)\nGender: \(gender)\nProfile Picture: \(profilePicture)\n\n")
            self.currentUser?.handle = handle as! String
            self.currentUser?.name = name
            self.senderDisplayName = name
            self.currentUser?.profilePicture = profilePicture as! String
            self.currentUser?.gender = gender as! String
        }
    })
}
```

In that function, I tried to append both arrays, exactly the same way, as a test:

```
self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))
self.currentUser?.rooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))
```

When I printed them on the next line, the `usersRooms` array was full of the `Room` objects as intended. However the array in `User`, `currentUser.rooms`, was nil. It's still nil even if I try to say `self.currentUser?.rooms = self.usersRooms`.

Why is it that I can set the `usersRooms` array but not the same array in my object?

Comment: If `self.currentUser` is `nil` then the optional chaining `self.currentUser?.rooms.append()` or `self.currentUser?.rooms = ...` does .... nothing!

Comment: @MartinR But shouldn't `self.currentUser?.rooms` populate with the append, like how the `usersRooms` array is populating? They're the same thing, i..e an array of type `Room`, so why is one populating with the append but the other isn't? Basically I'm confused as to why one is working and the other isn't, when they're both a `var *whatever*: [Room] = []`

Comment: Lookup "optional chaining" in the Swift book. If `a` is `nil` then `a?.whatever...` simply does nothing. And where should the current user come from, if you don't assign it?

Comment: `currentUser` is the `User` object, initialized in the view controller with `var currentUser: User?`. And all the other currentUser values are set without issue, it's just the `rooms` that I have this problem with, so I'm wondering what I can do to set `rooms`, just like I successfully set all the other values in the same function. And as I said, why can I set `var usersRooms: [Room] = []`, but not `var rooms: [Room] = []`?